# Pulling Docker Images from Private Repository using REGISTRY REST API

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-registry

I setup a private docker registry (localhost:5000) and pushed an image (busy_box_r:latest) there.

Now I am trying to pull images from private registry by using below command:

docker pull localhost:5000/busybox_r:latest

It is working fine, I can verify it by running command:

```
docker@default:~$ docker images
```

REPOSITORY                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

localhost:5000/busybox_r                latest              00f017a8c2a6        2 weeks ago         1.11 MB

Now I am trying to do the same with REGISTRY REST API:

I got the menifest file : http://192.168.99.100:5000/v2/busybox_r/manifests/latest

& also downloaded blob file (fs layer):

wget http://192.168.99.100:5000/v2/busybox_r/blobs/sha256:04176c8b224aa0eb9942af765f66dae866f436e75acef028fe44b8a98e045515

but this is just a file (that contains related binary data). How to load this blob file, so that i can see corresponding image on local system by running this command:

```
docker@default:~$ docker images
```